# How to Lower Power Consumption while still running tasks?

Tags: windows-vista, power-management

On my pc, I have Norton 360 installed. Since it takes up lots of resources, I usually just leave it on while I let it scan my computer, but I'm starting to think it takes up a lot of power. Is there any easy ways to let it continue while saving more energy?

I already have my computer on Power Saving mode, and turn the brightness down.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a display for that to run, so the first step would be turning your brightness (actually your screen) *off*.

Other than that, all you can really do is ensure that when it is running there are no other background processes running (i.e. make sure that all of the power consumption is for that program and the OS).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it isn't using as much power as you think.  First just turn your monitor off, unless you have a CRT and not a LCD monitor it is not using that much power.  I have an actual power meter and my monitor uses $0.80 a month.

My PC uses $17.23 a month, but I have the fastest AMD 8 core process and a power hungry radeon 7970.  As I am a gamer I frequently cause them both to use lots of power.  Probably 2/3 of the cost of my power is the video card. Surfing the web and etc is <200w but gaming is as high as 500w.  I wouldn't worry about Norton using lots of power, it probably isn't.